# Wait for inline js to load/finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have both inline js and external js on website.

I have problem because in external js I need variable that was is defined in inline js, but to my surprise external js happens to soon and yells at me that said variable is not defined.

It works if I use `$(document).ready()`, yet that is too late for me. I need something similar but less "powerful", waiting only for inline js to finish, not waiting for DOM to finish.

Is there function that waits for inline js to finish, or at least for variable to be defined?

Only thing i could think of was using timer that would periodically wait if needed variable is defined, but that is obviously ugly solution.

Comment: Why is document.ready too late?

Comment: You could use a callback in your inline-js, or rearrange the order of your js. But it should be best practice to wrap your code in a `ready` handler when working with jQuery

Comment: With external JS you mean an external file you own, right? I don't recommend inline JS. Can you explain why you are using external and inline JS?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I need to make impresion event trough google tag manager's dataLayer for google analytics. See https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#promo-impressions "This example assumes that
information about the promotions displayed is available when the page loads." code below has to be execute before DOM ready, otherwies it is too late and GA wont register it.

Comment: @Tom I know, that is why I am using inline js only for variable definitions that differ between each page-view. It is really just some variable definitions. Everything else I put to external JS. If I would put these variable definitions in external file as well, I could not let user to cache result file and that would be IMHO worse them using inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no separate event for "inline javascript ready" because a script tag is just a tag and, as such, it can appear at any position within a document. Even at the very end. So, it seems to me, your only two options (one really) are to:

1. Use DOM ready event
2. Reorganize your code to remove this load time dependency. Which makes me think: isn't including link to your external JS just **after** your inline block enough?